# Sub jar deployment

Tags: java, deployment, jar

`Collect.jar` is a part of jar file is in main project.
This is my classpath file, I want to deploy `collect.jar` file without whole project deployment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="lib"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/COLLECT.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/DA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/DAWIN.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/resource.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

if I put specific path for `collect.jar`, does it possible to make deploying? 
I try it but the project seems working with old `collect.jar`.
I am changing that collect jar path after create the whole project jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="lib"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/SMDABatchCall/smdacall_lib/COLLECT.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/DA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/DAWIN.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/resource.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with COLLECT.SER file (whic is serializable of .jar file) 
I put this file into main whole project jar file after opened it with winrar